# Shell Script for local file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, freeswitch

I am trying to install freeSwitch in my CentOS 6.5 machine. I have followed the instructions given at https://confluence.freeswitch.org/display/FREESWITCH/CentOS+6.

While executing make command I am facing problem of time out while downloading a library from ***files.freeswitch.org*** at terminal.

While if I paste the url in browser I am able to download the file. The instruction for downloading is written at a script file.

Now I want to change the script so that instead of doing a wget from url it should read it from the local disk. As I am very new to shell scripting. How I should change the script to get the desired result. the file name of script is getlib.sh and the script is

Please help

```
#!/bin/sh
##### -*- mode:shell-script; indent-tabs-mode:nil; sh-basic-offset:2 -*-

TAR=/bin/gtar
ZCAT=/bin/gunzip
BZIP=/usr/bin/bzip2
XZ=/usr/bin/xz
WGET=/usr/bin/wget
CURL=/usr/bin/curl

if [ -f "$WGET" ]; then
   DOWNLOAD_CMD=$WGET
elif [ -f "$CURL" ]; then
   DOWNLOAD_CMD="$CURL -O"
fi

if [ -n "`echo $1 | grep '://'`" ]; then
    base=$1/
    tarfile=$2
else
    base=http://files.freeswitch.org/downloads/libs/
    tarfile=$1
 fi

 uncompressed=`echo $tarfile | sed 's/\(\(\.tar\.gz\|\.tar\.bz2\|\.tar\.xz\)\|\(\.tgz\|\.tbz2\)\)$//'`

case `echo $tarfile | sed 's/^.*\.//'` in
     bz2|tbz2) UNZIPPER=$BZIP ;;
     xz) UNZIPPER=$XZ ;;
     gz|tgz|*) UNZIPPER=$ZCAT ;;
esac

if [ ! -d $tarfile ]; then
   if [ ! -f $tarfile ]; then
      rm -fr $uncompressed
      $DOWNLOAD_CMD $base$tarfile
      if [ ! -f $tarfile ]; then
         echo cannot find $tarfile
         exit 1
      fi
    fi
 if [ ! -d $uncompressed ]; then
    $UNZIPPER -c -d $tarfile | $TAR -xf -
 fi
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: your script is a basic unzipper. Just download the file and extract it with `file-roller` or using the apropriate comand line (`tar`, `gzip`, ...)

Comment: Looks like you are behind the proxy server. I suggest you to set `http_proxy` variable in your bash to access internet.

Comment: Yes. I jus realized that I am not able to download anything using wget command. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ -n "`echo $1 | grep '://'`" ]; then
    base=$1/
    tarfile=$2
```

Your script is already setup to use your downloaded file. Just run your script giving it the PATH as $1 and the downloaded filename as $2. For example if the script name is `freeSwitch` and the PATH where you downloaded the tarball is `/home/user1/files/` and the tarball name is `freeswitch.tar.bz2`, then simply run:

```
./freeSwitch /home/user1/files/ freeswitch.tar.bz2
```

That should start the script using the tarball from your local disk instead of trying to download it from http://files.freeswitch.org/downloads/libs/. **NOTE** you need the trailing `/` at the end of PATH. Good luck!